# Completely new to designing a website. Need to change colour of menu in another page

Tags: wordpress

So basically I need to change the color of the menu on one page, then all other pages would remain with their original color. How do I do this in Wordpress? Or CSS Hero, or Microthemer?

Answer (score 0):

### Two ways to do this in Wordpress:

**Wordpress Plugin**

You can find a plugin that enables you to add some CSS to overwrite your theme's original CSS file. It's easy to use but I wouldn't recommend it if you know a little bit about PHP and CSS. Here is an [exemple plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/).

---

**Child Theme**

This is the best way because you can basically change anything that has to do with your Wordpress theme without having to change the actual theme. However it requires a little more work and knowledge in PHP. Some good starting point: [how to create and customize a child theme](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/) and the official Wordpress [wiki page on child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). Also never modify directly your theme files let that be CSS or PHP files, always use a child theme!

For both methods you'll need a minimum of CSS of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use page id in css like if the page is home page, .home .main-menu li a{color:blue !important;}